# cordova installation warning (use uuid instead)

Tags: cordova

I tried to install Cordova for ionic. But unfortunately, below warning showed up!

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo npm install -g cordova` The `sudo` gives proper administrator access AND what you have there in the question is just a warning, warnings don't usually break code but errors do so next time provide the error please.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` (It's the one displayed in the errors when you try to install)
2. Delete the Cordova folder
3. Install Cordova (`npm install -g cordova`)